Ubuntu 22.04 automatically unsuspending if music is playing
Since updating to 22.04, closing the lid (on Lenovo x1) while music is playing automatically pauses the music as the computer suspends. So far so good. Curiously, a few seconds later, the computer automatically unsuspends and continues to play the music, before suspending again, being caught in an endless suspend/unsuspend loop. As far as I can tell this doesn't happen when no music is playing before suspending.
How can I stop/troubleshoot this?
